# clearing chromedriver cache - java

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation, selenium-chromedriver, safaridriver

Is there a way to clear chromedriver cache using a selenium API or a javascript?

I have already tried the following:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + pathOfChromeProfile);
                //options.addArguments("-incognito");
                options.addArguments("-disable-cache");

                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_APPLICATION_CACHE, false);
```

I have also tried the Java Script 
I have to interact with an extension that is not available in Incognito and therefore it is not an option.

I will appreciate a similar solution for SafariDriver as well.

Comment: Hi , Please take a look at this article [link](http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/1cc78f58ab29/java-clear-browser-cache-using-selenium-webdriver.html)

Comment: thank you but I am not trying to delete cookies but I am trying to delete browser cache. Application I am working with stores data in browser cache for its state to be persistent but I have multiple test cases that assume that the persistent state is not available (they have to test some previous state in the flow.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes - by using a fresh profile each time.

Each test should have its own WebDriver instance.  Don't "share browsers."  If you share browsers, the cache does not clear.  Conversely, having each test launch its own browser - starts automatically with a fresh cache.

Comment: I am not sharing browser and I am using a new Chrome driver instance for all my test cases. By new user profile you mean path to a User Data Director?